# JSON Swift unwrap [""]

Tags: json, swift

Im having an issue unwrapping my string correctly with SwiftyJSON

> output: ["AAPL"]

```
          stockData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)

            let json = try JSON(data: stockData)

 if let jsonArray = json["Stock Quotes"].array {

                let ticker = String(describing: jsonArray.map({$0["1. symbol"].stringValue}))

                print(ticker)



            }
```

JSON

sorry here is the full JSON

```
  {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Batch Stock Market Quotes",
        "2. Notes": "IEX Real-Time Price provided for free by IEX (https://iextrading.com/developer/).",
        "3. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Stock Quotes": [
        {
            "1. symbol": "AAPL",
            "2. price": "168.3500",
            "3. volume": "34941964",
            "4. timestamp": "2018-04-06 16:55:36"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Share the JSON.

Comment: `.map` returns an array, add .first at the end

Comment: returns first character A

Comment: I ment `}).first`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let jsonArray = json["Stock Quotes"].array {
       if let ticker =  jsonArray[0]["1. symbol"] as? String {
           print(ticker)
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the printed value above ?

Comment: Error - conditional binding must have optional type, Not JSON

Comment: Could you do that again ?

Comment: jsonDict = json["Stock Quotes"] is giving me the error on that too

Comment: Your updated JSON is missing Stock Quotes. If you are not having that, check the updated answer

Comment: That is very misleading. It is now that you have updated the complete JSON.

Comment: That is the full JSON I am sorry for misleading.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: No worries. Good luck ahead !!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
  if let jsonArray = json["Stock Quotes"].array {

           if let ticker =  jsonArray[0]["1. symbol"] as? String {

               print(ticker)

           }
   }
```

Comment: I was also guessing the same thing. But as per his JSON, Stock Quotes isn't an array. Also, in the latest JSON he has uploaded, Stock Quotes is missing.